# VS Code .Net Web API doesn't allow me to debug

Tags: c#, .net, macos, debugging, webapi

My .Net Web API program keeps showing me the same error whenever I try to debug it. Here is the error:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.IO.IOException
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5082: address already in use

I'm programming on Macbook M1 and VS Code btw.

It didn't help changing the port number.

I run it by typing `dotnet run` on terminal, after it started running I select the .NET Core Launch (web) configuration and click the run button on VS Code Run and Debug component. If I click this button without starting the program or just click Run->Start Debugging, it can't find the localhost on that port number. However, running the program on Swagger with `dotnet watch run` does not cause any problem, it works perfectly.

I've checked if that port number really in use by typing `lsof -i 5082` before running the program but nothing showed up. I feel like `dotnet run`+<kbd>Run and Debug</kbd> button combination tries to run the program twice but I couldn't find the proper way to do it.

Comment: You need to make sure you're running `lsof` with sufficient privileges too (as `lsof` will hide processes you don't have permission to see, even if they are using that port number)

Comment: @Dai It doesn't give any "port is already in use"errors when I try to run it with "dotnet watch run"

Comment: When you say "terminal window" - do you mean the macOS Terminal/zsh app, or the Terminal panel/window within VS Code?

Comment: @Dai I'm using MacOS terminal to use "lsof" command, VS Code terminal for other things I've mentioned.

Comment: What happens if you run `lsof` within VSCode? And exactly what build/version of macOS are you running?